# Can I view Shared Albums in the iCloud Photos web interface?

Tags: icloud, photos, sharing

I just switched to using the iCloud Photo Library and I enjoy the possibility to view my photos on any computer via the icloud.com web interface.

However, my [Shared Albums](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202786) do not appear in the iCloud Photos web interface.

Is that a limitation of icloud.com, or are there any steps to enable shared albums on icloud.com?

Answer (score 28):

You can’t as of December 2018:

[image: No shared albums.]

Comment: as of December 2020 still can't. Enjoy new emojis though.

Comment: as of August 2021 still can't.

Comment: as of December 2021 still can't

Comment: as of March 2022 still can't

Comment: As of June 2022 still can't

Comment: November 2022, still no dice :-(

Comment: Januar 2023 - still nope. Apples shared album feature is such a half effort it's laughable. As a backup i tried just sharing the link with the "Create public website" from my phone, but then the album is sorted by date added, completely useless for actual presentations.

Comment: as of April 2023, still can't

Comment: as of July 2023 still can't

Comment: If you open the album, click the little head icon, you can enable "Public Website" and "Share Link", then you can open in the browser, but this is a really stupid limitation that I can't just see the shared albums in the sidebar like we all expect to be possible.

Comment: as of January 2024, still can't. :-/

Answer (score 7):

You can make any Shared Album visible on the web as a public website:

> You can even share albums with friends and family who don't use iCloud. Just open a Shared Album that you created, go to the People tab on your iOS device or click the people icon on your Mac, and turn on Public Website. Your photos publish to a website that anyone can see in an up-to-date web browser.
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202786

In Photos, select the shared album, click on your little "head" icon on the top right to show the Public Website option.

[image: Public Website]

> **Public Website**
> Allow anyone to view this shared album on iCloud.com

Check Public Website. Distribute URL.

Comment: I think you miss the point. Of course one can share to the world and as such you the owner can now see them too. The fact that as the owner who creates the shared album can't see all their shared album on icloud.com website is really dumb!! The fact that a work around is to share with the world defeats the purpose of selective sharing.

Comment: How do find out what the URL is on which the album can be viewed?

Comment: In this case, Apple really sucks. The feature is missing since years!

Comment: @BrunoRijsman as of 2022 you may view your links on the iCloud site. On the photos sidebar, under *Photos* you have *iCloud Links*.

Comment: @Vaiden when I click it, I have an empty view with "Share Photos and Videos" button, but none of the shared albums I have appear here. It would be an acceptable half measure at least. But the best solution would be under Albums > Shared Albums. But I guess apple are too busy to fix their busted up, half baked software