# How do I share an entire album in iCloud photos? Not just individual pictures

Tags: icloud, photos.app, sharing

I have several albums with photos taken on an iPhone, which I view and work with at https://www.icloud.com/photos/. I can select individual pictures and create a share link, and I do this all the time.

But when I select an album, all the share links ghost out.

[image: ghosted share links iCloud web photos]

How can I use iCloud Photo to share whole albums with others?

PS: I'm aware of [How can I share an iCloud photo album?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229453/how-can-i-share-an-icloud-photo-album) but this recommends to use iCloud Photo Sharing which isn't available from iCloud Photos.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Shared Albums are not currently available on the web:
[Can I view shared photo albums on the icloud.com web interface?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194248/can-i-view-shared-photo-albums-on-the-icloud-com-web-interface)

---

You cannot share albums created on your iPhone or Mac or on iCloud Photos with other iCloud users.

These albums *are* synced to your other devices via iCloud, which is why you can see them on the web.

In the image you are attempting to share a normal album. These cannot be shared.

You must use the dedicated "Shared Albums" feature of iCloud Photos. This is different than the "Albums" feature, which you cannot share.

Shared Albums are not available via the web interface.

Comment: That's the answer already available on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229453/how-can-i-share-an-icloud-photo-album. The question here is how to use sharing from within iCloud Photos (not from the Photos app on the Mac or the iDevice).

Comment: @nohillside see my edit. This question *is* a duplicate of that one, then.

Comment: The answer could be the same, even if the question is different.  I'm approaching this from the iCloud side, expecting it would give me access to everything.

Comment: Is there a way to use the web interface to organize photos in a shared album?  The shared albums I created on the iPhone don't show up on a Mac in iPhoto, nor do they show up in iCloud.  It's iConfusing.

Comment: @Bryce shared albums seem to [not be visible *at all* on the iCloud website](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194248/can-i-view-shared-albums-in-the-icloud-photos-web-interface). And you cannot share the Albums that you *can* see. Agree that this is a very iBad experience.

Comment: @Bryce the shared albums should show up on the Mac in Photos, though. Ensure that every device has been plugged in and given enough time to sync.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create a shared photo album from iCloud.com.

The only way, as of this writing, to create as shared photo album is from the Photos app on an iOS device or the Photos application on a macOS device.

Comment: Thank you that's useful.  I've created a shared album from an iPhone, but that album does not appear in iCloud photos.

Comment: I meant that you can't do this on iCloud Photos at all.  You can only create and share a photo album from a device and not on the web.